# middleware laravel

Tags: laravel

buenas tardes podrían ayudarme con un middleware, necesito que si un usuario ya completo un formulario de registro me mande directamente al perfil de ese usuario y si no que me mande al formulario de completado de registro.
el middleware es el siguiente.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Modelos\Paciente;

use App\Helpers\Session_usuario;

use App\Helpers\General;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Closure;

use App;

use DB;

use Auth;

use Session;


class Registro_completadoMiddleware
{
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

           if ($request->Paciente()->telefono_principal === null) {
                return redirect('completar_registro');                        
                }


        return $next($request);
    }}
```

Comment: colocar que urge no ayuda en nada, aquí se poya pero debes ser paciente

Comment: no era mi intención ofenderte solo es que aun no lo soluciona y me preocupa disculpa

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona? ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: me dice que el metodo Paciente no existe

Comment: En ese caso, se necesita saber como llama tu controlador al metodo handler. En tu ejemplo $request deberia tener un metodo Paciente, pero no suele ser el caso. Normalmente deberias cojer el objeto user que lleve paciente dentro (o en su defecto, el parametro) que quieres. Has probado un `print_r($request)` para ver que tiene?

Comment: probablemente necesites hacer algo tipo `if($equest->input('telefono_principal') == null)`... ya que el `$request` debe contener los input con los parametros que le pases a la funcion...

Comment: voy a intentarlo de esa manera

Comment: me funciona así como me lo dices, pero al llenar ese formulario y guardar debería mandarme al perfil por que telefono_principal ya no esta null en la DB pero no me manda al perfil

Comment: Por eso necesitariamos saber como esta hecho el controlador que llama a la funcion handle. No sabemos que closure esta enviando, ni si es correcto el proceso de ese closure.

Comment: yo lo llamo en el constructor de mi controlador , pero no entiendo la parte del:" controlador que llama al handle" podría explicarme esa parte a lo mejor es mi error